# Count Distinct over multiple dimensions

Tags: visualization, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to find a way to find unique combinations of up to 4 columns on Amazon Quicksight, for example, the table below should result in 5 unique combinations, as there is 1 repetition.

| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Y | Z | A |
| X | Y | Z | B |
| Q | R | S | B |
| Q | R | S | B |
| Q | P | S | A |
| Q | P | S | B |

I have tried to utilize `distinct_countIf()` and put them in a list. I have also tried to create a calculated field that attempts to do the distinct filtering, unsuccessfully.

Upon reading the documentation, it seems `distinct_countIf()` works for **a** measure or **a** dimension, so I concluded it is not possible. But if anyone knows a way to implement this, that would be great!

Thank you!